# Unit test Apache Camel specific routes by filtering (Model#setRouteFilter)

Tags: apache-camel

How to include only certain routes in my unit test. For example, how do I enable only `my-translation-route`.

```java
public class TestRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("ftp://my-ftp-server:21/messages")
                .routeId("my-inbound-route")
                .to("direct:my-translation-route");

        from("direct:my-translation-route")
                .routeId("my-translation-route")
                .bean(MyBean.class)
                .to("direct:my-outbound-route");

        from ("direct:my-outbound-route")
                .routeId("my-translation-route")
                .to("http://my-http-server:8080/messages");
    }
}
```

I tried with Model#filterRoutes but this did not work. All routes were loaded.

```java
class TestRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new TestRoute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @Test
    void testIfItWorks() throws Exception {
        context.setRouteFilterPattern("my-translation-route", null);

        AdviceWith.adviceWith(context, "my-translation-route", a -> {
            a.mockEndpointsAndSkip("direct:my-outbound-route");
        });

        context.start();

        getMockEndpoint("mock:direct:my-outbound-route").expectedBodyReceived().expression(constant("Hahaha! 42"));

        template.sendBodyAndHeaders("direct:my-translation-route", "42", null);

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

I got it working with the override of `CamelTestSupport#getRouteFilterIncludePattern`, e.g.:

```java
@Override
public String getRouteFilterIncludePattern() {
    return "direct:my-translation-route";
}
```

But then this is set for all tests in this test class.

Comment: unless you have a good reason to keep all those routes in the same class, I would suggest to simply separate the route that needs to be tested alone in it's proper class, in general each route should be declared separately to keep design clean and ease tests and maintenance

Answer (score 0):

Possible (stupid) solution : set a conditional auto startup for your routes, whose value depends on a (Camel or JVM) property that you can set with a particular value during the unit tests:

```
public class TestRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @PropertyInject(name="productionMode", defaultValue="true")
    private boolean productionMode;

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("ftp://my-ftp-server:21/messages")
               ...
                .autoStartUp(productionMode); // <=here
     }
       
}
```

There are various ways to override properties during your tests. See https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/properties-component.html